# Apply shader to entire Threejs scene

Tags: three.js

I am working on a Threejs project. I am hoping to apply a custom shader to the entire scene, rather than just an object. I'm very unexperienced with shaders so I'm not even sure if this concept makes sense, but is it possible to apply a shader to the renderer? Or maybe the camera?

It is a fragment shader if that makes a difference, but it would be nice to apply any type of shader in the future.

Comment: Add this line: `scene.overrideMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );` Or specify any custom material.

Comment: I think the OP may mean a postprocessing shader. Check out the examples [HERE](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_glitch)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply shaders to the scene with ✨ post-processing ✨.

Here is the link to three.js documentation about post-processing 
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing